# I need after sending pictures via bluetooth display on hardware,but picture data No greater than 2888 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need after sending pictures via bluetooth display on hardware, hardware engineers have a demand, I need to transfer the image data is not greater than 2888 bytes, but when I was in compressed image compression to more than 5000 bytes of time cannot be compressed, what should I do?

Comment: To be clear are you saying there is a limit of the size of image that can be transferred of 2888 bytes and after compression your image is greater than 5000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compress the Image multiple time As per Image Size Limit. You can follow the below approach for the Image ccompression,

```
    CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
    CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
    int maxFileSize = 2888;

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);

    while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
    {
        compression -= 0.1;
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);
    }
```

Comment: I wrote it like this, but I can't continue to compress it

Comment: Can you elaborate more regarding same? What issue faced during Image compression? 1. An image compressed or Not 2. Do you want to exit function when It's done? 3. Do you want compressed image or not?

Comment: A slightly improved approach could be to set maxCompression to a reasonable lowest quality (like 0.4), and then start reducing the image pixel size more and more if maximum compression is not enough.